# How to make sure that all <div>s with float:right; actually float right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a div containing a number of inner divs with varying heights in order to create a two-column output similar to Facebook timeline, kind of like this:

```
<div style="width:600px">
<div class="boxsample" style="float:right;width=50%;">Content-right-1</div>
<div class="boxsample" style="float:left;width=50%;">Content-left-1</div>
<div class="boxsample" style="float:left;width=50%;">Content-left-2</div>
<div class="boxsample" style="float:right;width=50%;">Content-right-3</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that whenever the last left div is higher than the last right div, the next div always floats to the left of the last right one like this:
http://postimage.org/image/fi5ndamk5/
It appears to treat the hanging div on the right as a constraint that makes is float to the left of it.

How do I ensure that the float:right divs always actually float right?
(I am doing a while loop to fetch the content from a database, and I want to to specify the column the div belongs to just by using float, kind of like in Facebook timeline.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `clear: right` with the `float: right` divs and `clear: left` with the `float: left` divs. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgnUv/) for reference.

Comment: Upvoted, but -1 for using cluttered inline styles over simple CSS ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I hear you, but remember the point of my answer was to solve the problem at hand in the simplest way possible, not preach about my philosophies on beautiful code. I'm sure OP will never use inline styles in production code.

Comment: I tried this one before asking the question, and it did not work, because I have other columns besides the ones used in this div container. I should have mentioned that in my question. What has eventually worked for me is using clear selectively along with some elective position:absolute usage. Not a straightforward way, but it works for my layout.